# CSS Styling Not Taking Effect, Not sure why?

Tags: css

I know this is a NOOB question to most of you, but here is what Im trying to have it look like: **http://cssdesk.com/6Rzk2**  (Keep that link for the preview please)

However its just showing up as just plain text.

Thanks

Comment: there is no style being applied

Comment: I see the bottom border in your site.

Comment: make sure you have `#SumTitle` and `p#SumText` in your CSS file

Comment: I figured it out, its not that I didnt have the styling in my file, It was cloudflare, I had to purge the cloudflare cache. Its weird because I did NOT have to purge the cache to get the text to show up, But in order to get the styling effects to show up, I did have to purge the cache. Dont know why it was different, That's what threw me off. ughh. Thanks though! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you only have 2 style sheets being loaded on your site - style.css and large.css. Neither one has anything for #SumTitle. Add this to style.css and it will work -

```
#SumTitle {
color: #0D2F87;
border-bottom: 1px #3a6cc5 solid;
padding: 20px 0px 3px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px
}
```

Comment: I inspected the website and I saw the CSS rules O.o

Comment: I do though, I have the CSS pasted into the Style.css folder, looking at it right now and save it.

Comment: Ah, Just figured it out.  It was cloudflare,  I had to purge the cloudflare cache, ughh. Thanks though!